# sscanf and printf overwriting values

Tags: c, io

I am writing a simple c program that reads in a bunch of values from stdin using getline and sscanf.

The program apparently works: I invoke the function reading the line and print the results with printf. The problem arises when I just tried to print the values again, and the output is gibberish!

**-------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------**
I found the problem, reported in my own answer below. Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction!

My test input file is (with the 2 first lines to be skipped):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MODEL VALUE
500                     // X DIR
600                     // Y DIR
10.0                    // Grid Spacing
2e-4                    // Time step
80001                   // Max run iterations
```

And my code is:

Functions to read different kinds (separate from main just for clearness in the post)

```
int readint(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t size;
  int my_int;
  getline(&line, &size, stdin);
  sscanf(line,"%d",&my_int);
  return my_int;
}

double readfloat(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t size;
  float my_float;
  getline(&line, &size, stdin);
  sscanf(line,"%f",&my_float);
  return my_float;
}

char* readstr(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t size;
  getline(&line, &size, stdin);
  char * token = strtok(line, " ");
  return token;
}
int readvoid(void)
{
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t size;
  getline(&line, &size, stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

Main

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int dum;
  //- read in input file

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // MODEL VALUE
  dum=readvoid();
  dum=readvoid();
  #define Nx             (readint())            // run on 64 nodes
  #define Ny             (readint())          // Y DIR
  #define dx             (readfloat())         // Grid Spacing
  #define dt             (readfloat())       // Time step
  #define Max_Time       (readint())         // Max run iterations

  printf("model: %d,%d,%f,%f,%d\n",Nx,Ny,dx,dt,Max_Time);
  printf("model: %d,%d,%f,%f,%d\n",Nx,Ny,dx,dt,Max_Time);
  printf("model: %d,%d,%f,%f,%d\n",Nx,Ny,dx,dt,Max_Time);
  return 0;
}
```

With the first printf working just fine and the others outputting random values.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to c but have experience in fortran, shell, python, matlab and am a bit lost.

Comment: All those `read...` functions that call `getline()` are leaking memory. Also, they should initialize `size` to 0.

Comment: In a line of the form `foo(a(), b(), c())` it is indeterminate the order in which `a`, `b`, and `c` are called.  In other words, you're (probably) reading the values out of order.

Comment: The test input file as shown in the question only contains enough values for one of those three `printf` calls (which as pointed out by @WilliamPursell may be reading the parameter values in the wrong order). There is no error checking for end of file or valid input, so it is not surprising that you get junk output.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks! so I should initialise size_t size=0? Is it just that that is causing memory leaks? Again, no c expert here

Comment: @IanAbbott coming from fortran, this is not so clear to me. I read (successfully) the variables and defined them, which I assumed it means they are stored into memory. Why can't I print them more than once? In any other language I know this would work

Comment: The memory leak is because the memory allocated by `getline()` is never freed. (But you cannot free the memory for your `readstr()` function because the caller needs it.)

Comment: Why do you think you read anything successfully?  You didn't check the value returned by `getline`, so you don't know if you read anything.  You don't check the value returned by `sscanf`, so you don't know if you succesfully parsed anything.  And you didn't store the values in memory anywhere.  You passed them to `printf` and then discarded the values.

Comment: Note that `Nx`, `Ny`, etc. are not "variables", they are macros. If you want variables then define them as such, e.g.: `int Nx = readint();` `int Ny = readint();`, etc.

Comment: @IanAbbott `getline` won't allocate a buffer for you unless `size` is set to zero.  So it's worse than a memory leak, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom It depends which man page you believe, which is why I suggested initializing `size` to 0, but POSIX `getline` only considers it if `line` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the responses are "gibberish". `my_int` is not initialized, so if `sscanf` does not read a value, then `readint` is returning an uninitialized variable.  (aka, "gibberish").  Since you've already read the file and not rewound, `getline` is (probably) returning -1 and `sscanf` is not assigning a value.  But you can't tell, because your program does not check the values returned by either `getline` or `sscanf`.

You need to `rewind` the stream if you want to read it again.

Also, you cannot interleave the calls to `readint` and `readfloat` in the parameters list of printf.  The order in which they will be called is not fixed.

Comment: OK I think I got the main point: I thought that "define" was a simple way to declare a variable, but all I wanted to do is assign the result of, e.g. readint() to the variable Nx... while apparently I am re-calling the read functions every time! Correct?

Comment: Yes, `#define` is just a strict text replacement.  You want `int Nx = readint()`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, thanks to above comments:

I naively thought that #define was able to read the output of e.g. readint() and store it as an object-like macro (e.g. #define Nx 500), but apparently this is not the case.

Thanks everyone!